# Any Lua logging library to integrate with log4j?

Tags: logging, lua, log4j

The task is to log into the same file from different languages (Java, C++ and Lua) to keep log records in chronological order. I'm thinking about network or syslog appenders so I can easily log from different languages. Log4j is the most popular format and using log4cxx I can support Java and C++. I found Log4Lua but seems it's dead.

What solution can you recommend?

EDIT:

I need this on both Linux and Windows

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/164572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your best bet is to write a small C++ dll that exposes the functionality you want, load it into your lua script, and call the C++ functions that do the logging calls from lua that way.